# Reload the current URL in Cordova 5.0 webview?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-5.0.0

In cordova 5.0 , Reloadwebview has removed. so, Is there any alternative method to reload the current URL in webview.

Comment: How about fetching the URL using Javascript and use it to `document.open` or in whatever way you initially load the webview?